# Selenium: Connection refused and driver not found

Tags: java, selenium

I am running a selenium server locally to try to run some tests for Firefox on Linux. 
I run the server command like this:

`java -Dwebdriver.firefox.bin=/usr/bin/firefox -Dwebdriver.firefox.marionette=/home/niru/selenium/geckodriver -jar /home/niru/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.5.0.jar`

When I run the test command I notice a couple issues :
Error: `Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: connection refused`
Error: `Driver info: driver.version: unknown`
Issue: Output says `Binding default provider to: Org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService`

Following: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver I verified and made sure that my $PATH variable has `/home/niru/selenium/geckodriver`. When running the tests, a Firefox browser window also opens up.

Is there a reason why its using chromedriverservice and is unable to find driver version?

### Exception:

```
 [testng] Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: connection refused
   [testng] Build info: version: '3.5.0', revision: '8def36e068', time: '2017-08-10T23:00:22.093Z'
   [testng] System info: host: '<myhost>', ip: '<ip>', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.2.45-0.6.wd.865.49.315.metal1.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_112'
   [testng] Driver info: driver.version: unknown
   [testng] remote stacktrace: stack backtrace:
   [testng]    0:           0x4f388c - backtrace::backtrace::trace::h736111741fa0878e
   [testng]    1:           0x4f38c2 - backtrace::capture::Backtrace::new::h63b8a5c0787510c9
   [testng]    2:           0x442d88 - webdriver::error::WebDriverError::new::hea6d4dbf778b2b24
   [testng]    3:           0x449f99 - geckodriver::marionette::MarionetteHandler::create_connection::hf8b6061dba65cdd0
   [testng]    4:           0x42ac91 - <webdriver::server::Dispatcher<T, U>>::run::hba9181b5aacf8f04
   [testng]    5:           0x402c59 - std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h19de262639927233
   [testng]    6:           0x40c065 - std::panicking::try::do_call::h6c1659fc4d01af51
   [testng]    7:           0x5e38ec - panic_unwind::__rust_maybe_catch_panic
   [testng]                         at /checkout/src/libpanic_unwind/lib.rs:98
   [testng]    8:           0x420d32 - <F as alloc::boxed::FnBox<A>>::call_box::h953e5f59694972c5
   [testng]    9:           0x5dc00b - alloc::boxed::{{impl}}::call_once<(),()>
   [testng]                         at /checkout/src/liballoc/boxed.rs:661
   [testng]                          - std::sys_common::thread::start_thread
   [testng]                         at /checkout/src/libstd/sys_common/thread.rs:21
   [testng]                          - std::sys::imp::thread::{{impl}}::new::thread_start
   [testng]                         at /checkout/src/libstd/sys/unix/thread.rs:84
   [testng] Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
   [testng] System info: host: '<myhost>', ip: '<myip>', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.2.45-0.6....x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_152'
   [testng] Driver info: driver.version: unknown
   [testng]     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
   [testng]     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
   [testng]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
   [testng]     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
   [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57)
   [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104)
   [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$24(ProtocolHandshake.java:360)
   [testng]     at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
   [testng]     at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
   [testng]     at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
   [testng]     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
   [testng]     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
   [testng]     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
   [testng]     at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
   [testng]     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
   [testng]     at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
   [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:363)
   [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory.apply(ServicedSession.java:159)
   [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$createSession$15(ActiveSessionFactory.java:148)
   [testng]     at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
   [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ActiveSessionFactory.createSession(ActiveSessionFactory.java:148)
   [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.BeginSession.execute(BeginSession.java:69)
   [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.lambda$handle$0(WebDriverServlet.java:231)
   [testng]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
   [testng]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
   [testng]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
   [testng]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
   [testng]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Is `/home/niru/selenium/geckodriver` your folder where geckodriver exist or exact location of geckodriver?

Comment: The exact location of the geckodriver.

Comment: That's wrong as per doc and should point to folder containing the driver @Niru

Comment: Oh I see. So I think the export path needs to be the directory but the -D parameter needs to be the exact location.

Comment: Good to know that solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems is unable to load the geckodriver and try, for default, to load the chromedriver:

```
Binding default provider to: Org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService
```

You are using `selenium-server-standalone-3.5.0.jar`, the versions of the [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and of the browser that are you using, are recommended?

Anyway, make sure that the geckodriver is executable:

- chmod +x geckodriver

Comment: As an addition: I needed to update the PATH variable to be the directory and update Firefox.